# How does the Magnetometer work on my phone?

Tags: electromagnetism

I know that there are a bunch of hall effect sensors in my phone but my actual question is: How does the orientation and all the axis displayed on an app calculated and shown? How is the total strength calculated? And how reliable is it really?
I would like to use it for an upcoming experiment where i have to measure the strength of a bunch of electromagnets. 
I have a Oneplusone in case that helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetometer#Mobile_telephones

Comment: Maybe this will help you; Ozyagcilar, Talat: Implementing a tilt-compensated eCompass using accelerometer and magnetometer sensors https://cache.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN4248.pdf